# WIN32: Duplicate Standard Button Control (disabled Icon / hotkey underline) in Owner Draw Button?

Tags: winapi, comctl32

So for the simple feat of wanting to put an icon on the right side of button text instead of the left resulted in having to use owner draw buttons (but someone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69920478/win32-is-there-a-quick-way-to-only-add-an-icon-to-an-owner-draw-button/69922572#69922572) said Custom Draw is actually available if using visual themes).  Okay, fine, but now I'm finding you can't really duplicate what Windows standard buttons do when it's not in owner draw mode.

For a normal enabled button I can get the look correct by checking if visual styles are available or not and then using either the `DrawThemeBackground()` / `DrawThemeText()` or `DrawFrameControl()` / `DrawText()`.  However the hot key underline character is shown even when alt key is not pressed, the default buttons don't show it until alt pressed.

For a disabled button, I can't duplicate the disabled look of the icon placed on the button.  I tried `DrawState()` over `DrawIconEx()` but that looks like the old Windows 3.1 type grey graphic not the visual style dimmed graphic.  I see there is a `DrawThemeIcon()` for an image list, I guess I could try that (I'd have to test non visual style mode to see if `DrawState()` matches when not using visual styles).

Also, as you hover over the button, the state doesn't change, I understand that if using owner draw, that doesn't occur, maybe it would still work with Custom Draw?

So the two main questions are:

1 - Is there something built-in to the button / owner draw to handle the underlined hotkey only when alt was pressed?

***Update to Question 1:*** I found `DT_HIDEPREFIX` in `DrawText()` and using Custom Draw there is the `CDIS_SHOWKEYBOARDCUES` flag.  However with Owner Draw I'm not sure if there is a flag someplace?

2 - How do you draw an icon for a button that is disabled to match what default buttons do?

TIA!!

Answer (score 1):

For shortcut underline you can use `WM_QUERYUISTATE` to ask if it should be hidden or visible

```cpp
DWORD   draw_text_flags = ...;
if ( SendMessage( control_hwnd, WM_QUERYUISTATE, 0, 0 ) & UISF_HIDEACCEL ) != 0 )
{
    // hide prefix
    draw_text_flags |= DT_HIDEPREFIX;
}

// some combination of PBS_DEFAULTED, PBS_DISABLED, PBS_HOT, PBS_NORMAL, PBS_PRESSED; 
int state = ...; 
DrawThemeText( theme, hdc, BP_PUSHBUTTON, state, text, text_len, draw_text_flags, 0, rect );
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer to Q2: If you create an `HIMAGELIST` using `ILC_COLOR32 | ILC_MASK,` and use `ILD_NORMAL|ILD_BLEND25` on `ImageList_Draw()` it gives the same look as windows default buttons for a disabled button.

Answer (score -1):

Based on responses from @Remy-Lebeau and @Daniel-Sęk and reviewing various projects on CodeProject, I create an easy to use class to handle this.  It can be found at [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5317407/Win32-Cplusplus-Add-Icon-to-Right-Side-of-Button-T).  Thanks Guys.